# Accessing List and TextInput inside a movieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a problem accessing a List and TextInput fields placed inside an MC.
What I'm trying to do is an animation for a menu. So I placed buttons and List and a TextInput inside a MC which I want to animate.

I'm trying to access them like this:

```
string_variable = mc_name.textInput_Name.text;
```

Everything worked fine before I placed those controls inside an MC. The code was, of course, without mc_name. prefix before that.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? My goal is to make a complex keyframe animation of a clip with buttons and other controls inside it, specifically List and TextInput ones.

Thanks.

Comment: That line is correct, in and of itself; the problem would depend on the rest of the code.  Try putting a try...catch block around that and see what it catches, if anything.  Also show some more of the code having to do with this.

Answer (score 0):

Most animations, especially UI, like menu blocks, lists, could be done with [tweening engines](http://ntt.cc/2010/05/16/11-powerful-open-source-tweening-engine-for-actionscript.html). You will have more control over animated elements. MovieClip isn't a nice choice to use as mechanism to animate UI components that should be accessed.

Anyway, If you want MovieClips in your project, give same names to the components on the timeline on every keyframe. It will help, a bit...